# Does the Changeling ability count for Happily Ever After?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In Magic: The Gathering, there is a card that allows you to win automatically if you meet 3 specific conditions, one of which this question is about. On the card [Happily Ever After](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHappily%20Ever%20After%5d), it states that if there are six or more card types among permanents you control and/or cards in your graveyard (and the other conditions), then you win the game, but I am unsure if specific creature types count. The MTG Gatherer states that supertypes (such as legendary) do not count but I do not know if creature types count.

Comment: Please do not edit the answer into the question. The answers still exist on the page, and you can upvote them and/or accept one to show that they helped you.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for not giving credit.

Comment: Giving credit isn't the main point I was making. This is a question and answer site, and we keep the questions and answers separate and distinct. The question section of the post should contain just the question, and the answer section should contain just the answer. Since the answers are sorted based on upvotes and whether they are accepted, the most helpful ones are clearly visible to future viewers, so it's not beneficial to replicate that information in the question.

Comment: Sorry for not doing that. I'm new to the site, but that shouldn't be an excuse, and I will not do what I had done again. Thank you for helping, correcting my mistake (or just discrediting), and telling me! I will not do that again.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Do you mean "edit the answer into the question"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, creature types do not count as card types here.

One of the Gatherer rulings for Happily Ever After says

> **The card types that could appear among your permanents and cards in your graveyard are artifact, creature, enchantment, instant, land, planeswalker, and sorcery. Certain older sets contain tribal cards as well.** Supertypes, such as legendary and basic, aren’t card types.

Answer (score 5):

No, that won't work. Creature types are *sub*types and not card types.

> 205.2a The card types are artifact, conspiracy, creature, enchantment, instant, land, phenomenon, plane, planeswalker, scheme, sorcery, tribal, and vanguard. See section 3, “Card Types.”
>
> 205.3a A card can have one or more subtypes printed on its type line.
>
> 205.3m Creatures and tribals share their lists of subtypes; these subtypes are called creature types.

In regular games, you'll only see artifact, creature, enchantment, instant, land, planeswalker, sorcery, and finally tribal (which is never encountered alone, but always in combination with another card type).